# Lambda condition for linked object in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda

I am trying to write a named scope in a class for Invoice.  Invoice objects have a link to a Job object. Job objects have a link to a Company object.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :job

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :company
```

I want the scope to be base on whether the ID of the Company related to the Job matches the passed in value.

I am attempting it as something like this

```
named_scope :job_company, lambda{|job_company_id| {:conditions => {job.company.id => job_company_id}}}
```

This is giving me an error that says

> undefined local variable or method `job' for #Class:0x103239160

How do I write the lambda function for this?

NB: I am using Ruby 1.8.7 with Rails 2.3.5

Comment: If the question's about Ruby on Rails, tag it as such.

Comment: Show us the relevant `belongs_to` and `has_xxx`. If it's `has_many :jobs` then replace `job` with `jobs`.

Comment: The question relates to the Ruby language, which is why I originally tagged it as Ruby.  Updated to show belongs_to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A named_scope is basically just a class method, so inside the lambda, the scope of self is Invoice. There is no job instance or local variable, hence the error.

But, this should work:

```
named_scope :job_company, lambda{|job_company_id| { :joins => { :job => :company }, :conditions => ["jobs.company_id = ?", job_company_id] }}
```

Comment: Isn't the scope of self `Invoice` and not `Job` in @link664's example?

Comment: Yes, the scope of self is Invoice.  I am trying to use the named scope to filter Invoice objects, based on the company object assigned to the Job object that is assigned to the Invoice objects.

Comment: totally understand how that goes ;) Btw, thanks for paperclip.